# Powershell - How to out-host and set a variable with the ouput

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell snippet:

```
$output = & "$backup.exe" @("/remoteShare", $remoteShare)  2>&1
```

This sets $output but the problem with is it does not write the output of backup.exe to the command console window. As a solution I tried:

```
$output = & "$backup.exe" @("/remoteShare", $remoteShare)  2>&1 | out-host
```

This solution outputs to the command console window but the $output is null.

tl;dr How do I run an exe from PS and display the output of that exe to the command console AND save the output in a variable??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```powershell
$output = & "$backup.exe" @("/remoteShare", $remoteShare)  2>&1
$output
```

or:

```powershell
& "$backup.exe" @("/remoteShare", $remoteShare)  2>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable output
```

### See:

[`Tee-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937(v=wps.630).aspx)

Comment: The first solution doesn't work as it is a long running process so I need to output in realtime. The second solution with Tee-Object works great though!

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap an expression that uses indirection (assigning a result to a variable using the = operator) in parens, it will set the variable and also output the result:

```
($output = & "$backup.exe" @("/remoteShare", $remoteShare)  2>&1)
```

If you explicitly want it to go to the console, you can pipe that to out-host:

```
($output = & "$backup.exe" @("/remoteShare", $remoteShare)  2>&1) | out-host
```